# How to print just the file name when looping through all files of a directory

Tags: bash

Imagine there are these 3 subdirectories inside my directory:

```
dfcg7 yhjs6 gbggse3
```

Inside each of this subdirectories there is a `txt` file, which I would like to use in another program, so I would like to print all the relative paths to this files.

I am trying:

```
for file in /mnt/lustre/mydir*
do
        printf "$file/*.txt \t"
done
```

and I also tried:

```
for file in /mnt/lustre/mydir*
do
        printf "$file"/*.txt "\t"
done
```

but in both cases, my output is this:

```
/mnt/lustre/mydir/dfcg7/*txt/mnt/lustre/mydir/yhjs6/*txt/mnt/lustre/mydir/gbggse3/*txt
```

1. My output is no tab separated
2. It is printing the full path, instead of the relative
3. It is not printing the file name inside each subdirectory

So, my desired output would be this:

```
dfcg7/fileA.txt    yhjs6/fileB.txt    gbggse3/fileC.txt
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The glob does not expand inside quoutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the path prefix in a variable:

```sh
prefix=/mnt/lustre/mydir
```

Assign the files to an array:

```sh
files=("$prefix"/*/*.txt)
```

And then print the array, tab separated, while removing the prefix from each element:

```
$ (IFS=$'\t'; printf '%s\n' "${files[*]/#"$prefix"\/}")
dfcg7/fileA.txt gbggse3/fileC.txt       yhjs6/fileB.txt
```

This uses a subshell to contain the scope of the modified `IFS`.

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain this output, but as a string? `"dfcg7/fileA.txt gbggse3/fileC.txt       yhjs6/fileB.txt"`

Comment: @Jeni You can assign the output of the last statement with `out=$(IFS=$'\t'; printf ...)`

Comment: If I do that then my variable "out" contains each line for each file, while I just want the filename. 

When I do:
`$out`

This is the output I get:

`dfcg7/fileA.txt: line 190: protein_coding: command not found
dfcg7/fileA.txt: line 190: protein_coding: command not found
dfcg7/fileA.txt: line 190: protein_coding: command not found`

While my desired output would be: `"dfcg7/fileA.txt gbggse3/fileC.txt yhjs6/fileB.txt"`

Comment: @Jeni Did you mean to do `echo "$out"`? Just `$out` tries to run the contents of the variable as shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick solution that I've been able to come up with

```
RESULT=""
for file in /path/to/you/files/*; do
    OUTPUT=$(ls $file/*txt)
    RESULT="$RESULT:$OUTPUT"
done
# replace every : with a tab symbol and remove the first tab
echo $RESULT | tr ':' '\t' | gsed -r 's/^\s+//g'
```

Notice that I've used `gsed` here. It is a GNU sed available for MacOS. If you are using Linux you can simply use `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
for file in /mnt/lustre/mydir/*/*.txt; do
  printf '%s\t%s\t%s' "${file#*/*/*/*/}"
done
```

Output

```
dfcg7/fileA.txt         gbggse3/fileC.txt               yhjs6/fileB.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
cd /mnt/lustre/mydir
for file in */*.txt
do
        printf "%s\t" "$file"
done
printf "\n"
```

Or easier:

```sh
(cd /mnt/lustre/mydir; ls -d */*.txt | tr '\n' '\t'); echo
```

The last `echo` is to append a `\n` at the end, but if you don't need it, you can leave it out.